# How should I prevent module naming conflicts in RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have three RequireJS modules with simple module names (like `api` for example) that will be used on pages that follow a plugin-based architecture, so I do not have full control on what other modules get defined. So, I'd like to create a unique non-global "namespace" to ensure that some other code hasn't already defined an `api` and a naming conflict occurs.

For example, instead of using `define('api')`, I would do `define('myns.api')` or something similar.

How should I solve this?

This is the [project](https://github.com/IronCountySchoolDistrict/Extended-Schema-Client-Library) that I'm referring to. Also, I'm using Grunt to build my project.

Answer (score 0):

This is a much deeper problem than it might seem like on the surface with no single good answer.

Package managers like NPM often set up a namespace similar to `username.projectname.modulename`.

For namespaced languages like ActionScript and C# it's common to use the domain of the project similar to `com.example.module`

In other situations where it's difficult to come up with a name at all, a GUID is generated and used to uniquely identify the module.